# Django Redirect: No errors, but no redirect

Tags: python, django

I `POST` some data via an HTML form using AJAX to modify data in my database. The data is successfully modified by executing stored procedures on the DB. Final line of the `view.py` function call is `return redirect('Home')`.

The redirect is successfully executing, but I am not being redirected. I can overcome this by adding `window.location.href = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/`  in the success function of the AJAX call. The problem is, I want to use `messages.success(request, 'Data Successfully Updated')`, which only appears after refreshing the AJAX-originating redirect.

Is there a reason why `return redirect('Home')` is not working here, and is there a way to overcome this?

`Home` is the name of my path in `urls.py`

```
[06/May/2021 17:23:52] "POST /search/ HTTP/1.1" 302 0   // submitting changes to database
[06/May/2021 17:23:55] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 4750        // The page I am intending to redirect to
```

**Ajax Call**

```
function updateCards(){
    ajaxUpdCard().done()
    function ajaxUpdCard() {
        return $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '',
            data: {csrfmiddlewaretoken: window.CSRF_TOKEN, Action: 'Card', CardID: $('#currentCardID').val(),
                BCard: $('#sr-bad_card').val(), CNum: $('#sr-card_number').val(), CPin: $('#sr-pin_number').val(),
                Bal: $('#sr-balance').val()}
        })
    }
}
```

**views.py**

```
        if request.method == 'POST' and request.POST['Action'] == 'Card':
            cardID = request.POST['CardID']
            Bcard = int(request.POST['BCard'])
            CNum = int(request.POST['CNum'])
            CPin = int(request.POST['CPin']) if request.POST['CPin'] != '' and request.POST['CPin'] != 'XXXX' else 'Null'
            print(CPin)
            Bal = request.POST['Bal']
            update_card_transaction(entityID, userID, cardID, Bcard, CNum, CPin, Bal)
            messages.success(request, 'Data Successfully Updated')
            return redirect('Home')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shood return some data from backend side, and redirect on your clinet side

**views.py**

```
if request.method == 'POST' and request.POST['Action'] == 'Card':
            cardID = request.POST['CardID']
            Bcard = int(request.POST['BCard'])
            CNum = int(request.POST['CNum'])
            CPin = int(request.POST['CPin']) if request.POST['CPin'] != '' and request.POST['CPin'] != 'XXXX' else 'Null'
            print(CPin)
            Bal = request.POST['Bal']
            update_card_transaction(entityID, userID, cardID, Bcard, CNum, CPin, Bal)
            messages.success(request, 'Data Successfully Updated')
            return JsonResponse({'foo':'bar'})
```

Ajax Call

```
function updateCards() {
    ajaxUpdCard().done()
    function ajaxUpdCard() {
        return $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '',
            data: {
                csrfmiddlewaretoken: window.CSRF_TOKEN, Action: 'Card', CardID: $('#currentCardID').val(),
                BCard: $('#sr-bad_card').val(), CNum: $('#sr-card_number').val(), CPin: $('#sr-pin_number').val(),
                Bal: $('#sr-balance').val()
            },
            success:function(response) {
                window.location.href='/home'
                
            }
        })
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

redirect take as argument the full path as string or view name :

```
if request.method == 'POST' and request.POST['Action'] == 'Card':
                cardID = request.POST['CardID']
                Bcard = int(request.POST['BCard'])
                CNum = int(request.POST['CNum'])
                CPin = int(request.POST['CPin']) if request.POST['CPin'] != '' and request.POST['CPin'] != 'XXXX' else 'Null'
                print(CPin)
                Bal = request.POST['Bal']
                update_card_transaction(entityID, userID, cardID, Bcard, CNum, CPin, Bal)
                messages.success(request, 'Data Successfully Updated')
                return redirect(Home)
```

or you can use reverse :

```
if request.method == 'POST' and request.POST['Action'] == 'Card':
            cardID = request.POST['CardID']
            Bcard = int(request.POST['BCard'])
            CNum = int(request.POST['CNum'])
            CPin = int(request.POST['CPin']) if request.POST['CPin'] != '' and request.POST['CPin'] != 'XXXX' else 'Null'
            print(CPin)
            Bal = request.POST['Bal']
            update_card_transaction(entityID, userID, cardID, Bcard, CNum, CPin, Bal)
            messages.success(request, 'Data Successfully Updated')
            return redirect(reverse('Home'))
```

Comment: I tried your method, but it did not work.

Comment: are you sure that the home function is start with capital letter ?

Comment: return redirect(reverse('home'))

Comment: Yes, I confirmed the URL name several times...